# printer status changed to "Paused - "Rejecting Jobs" periodically

Tags: release-juno

OS Juno, printer status changed to "Paused - "Rejecting Jobs" periodically, maybe a few hours, or days. printer status will change.
have to do 'resume printer/accept jobs' in cups admin page.

have tried remove all printers and re-add. no luck.
printer operation policy is 'default'

[image: screenshot]

```
ken@element:/var/log/cups$ cat access_log
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:13 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:13 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:15 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 291 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:18 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 11004 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11004 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 12048 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12048 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:09:38:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:01:18 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 182 Renew-Subscription client-error-not-found
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:02:29 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 183 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:02:29 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 183 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:02:29 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 184 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:02:29 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 184 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:02:29 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:02:29 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:02:29 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:00 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:00 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:04 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 291 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:08 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 11004 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11004 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 12048 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12048 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:03:10 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:04:02 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 359 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:04:37 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 183 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:04:37 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 183 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:04:37 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 184 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:04:37 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 184 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:04:37 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:04:37 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:04:37 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:08 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:08 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:13 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 291 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:16 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 11004 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11004 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 12048 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12048 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:18 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:21 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 359 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:41 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 183 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:41 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 183 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:41 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 184 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:41 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 184 CUPS-Delete-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:41 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 401 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:05:41 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 123 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:05:41 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 152 Cancel-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:34 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 349 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:34 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:38 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 291 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:42 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 293 CUPS-Create-Local-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 11004 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11004 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 207 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 12048 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 12048 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:10:06:44 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 208 CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:10:06:50 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 359 Create-Printer-Subscriptions successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:05:10 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 182 Renew-Subscription successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:21 +0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 350 Create-Printer-Subscriptions client-error-bad-request
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 190 Pause-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:11:19:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 190 Pause-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 190 CUPS-Reject-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:11:19:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 190 CUPS-Reject-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 183 Pause-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:11:19:21 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 183 Pause-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 183 CUPS-Reject-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 183 CUPS-Reject-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 181 Pause-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 181 Pause-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 181 CUPS-Reject-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 181 CUPS-Reject-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 189 Pause-Printer successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 189 Pause-Printer successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 189 CUPS-Reject-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:11:19:22 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 189 CUPS-Reject-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:19:31 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 401 183 CUPS-Set-Default successful-ok
localhost - root [09/Nov/2018:11:19:31 +0800] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 183 CUPS-Set-Default successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:29:16 +0800] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_M3035_MFP_40EA4B HTTP/1.1" 200 290 Create-Job server-error-not-accepting-jobs
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:29:38 +0800] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_M3035_MFP_40EA4B HTTP/1.1" 200 284 Create-Job server-error-not-accepting-jobs
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:30:39 +0800] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_M3035_MFP_40EA4B HTTP/1.1" 401 144 CUPS-Accept-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:30:50 +0800] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_M3035_MFP_40EA4B HTTP/1.1" 401 144 CUPS-Accept-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - ken [09/Nov/2018:11:30:50 +0800] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_M3035_MFP_40EA4B HTTP/1.1" 200 144 CUPS-Accept-Jobs successful-ok
localhost - - [09/Nov/2018:11:30:56 +0800] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_M3035_MFP_40EA4B HTTP/1.1" 401 144 Resume-Printer successful-ok
localhost - ken [09/Nov/2018:11:30:56 +0800] "POST /printers/HP_LaserJet_M3035_MFP_40EA4B HTTP/1.1" 200 144 Resume-Printer successful-ok
ken@element:/var/log/cups$ cat error_log
E [09/Nov/2018:11:19:21 +0800] [Client 44] Returning IPP client-error-bad-request for Create-Printer-Subscriptions (no URI) from localhost
E [09/Nov/2018:11:29:16 +0800] [Client 156] Returning IPP server-error-not-accepting-jobs for Create-Job (ipp://localhost/printers/HP_LaserJet_M3035_MFP_40EA4B) from localhost
E [09/Nov/2018:11:29:38 +0800] [Client 156] Returning IPP server-error-not-accepting-jobs for Create-Job (ipp://localhost/printers/HP_LaserJet_M3035_MFP_40EA4B) from localhost
```

BR

Comment: This question may be related to this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/install-usb-printer/17135#17135

Answer (score 1):

There may be an issue with the Printers plug in settings or it's designed to disable the printers after being idle.

I am not comfortable using command line so I installed `synaptic` package manager from the [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter).

- Open synaptic package manager and do a search for `switchboard-plug-printers` and remove it.
- Then do a search for and install `system-config-printer`.

You can use it from command line as

```
sudo system-config-printer
```

. or you can install the `AppEditor` from [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter) and setup an icon in the Applications.

My printers all stay enabled and accepting jobs now.